# Where is the shortcut "Open in Blend" in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, blend

Sometimes I see the shortcut sometimes I don't. I'm not sure why.

How can I make the shortcut permanent?

Comment: For those voting for this thread to close, please provide a reason why. AFAIK, its a valid question and I cant find the solution in google.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I believe I have an answer.  It worked for me flawlessly.  After being frustrated, I wrote to MS through the Feedback option in VS2013 (at the top).  A week later, one of their employees responded with this:

> Hi,
>
> Thanks for raising this issue to us through the Visual Studio
>   Feedback program. I am interested in helping investigate the issue
>   you’ve described.   After creating a new WPF app in Visual Studio 2013
>   RTM, I was able to reproduce the issue you’ve described. By default,
>   .xaml files do not have the “Open in Blend…” command enabled in the
>   context menu in the Solution Explorer.   However, I was able to
>   successfully add this command in both VB and C# WPF projects in VS
>   2013. It sounds like you might have also tried this method, but please try the steps below and see if you are able to successfully add the
>   command. I hope that step #6 might be the trick in successfully
>   enabling the command for you.   In order to add this command, I
>   followed these steps:
>
> 1. Tools > Customize
> 2. Select Context Menu radio button
> 3. From the Dropdown, choose “Project and Solution Context Menus | Item”
> 4. Click the “Add Command…” button
> 5. Select View category
> 6. Select the third (bottom-most) “Open in Blend…” command (there should be three available)
> 7. Close dialogs
> 8. Right click MainWindow.xaml
> 9. Select “Open in Blend…” (it should not be grayed out)
>
> Of the three “Open in Blend…” commands available, the third one is the
>   only one which successfully worked on .xaml files in WPF projects. The
>   other two would be grayed out when I tried to use them.   Please
>   contact me to let me know if you are able to successfully add the
>   command or if you still see the issue. I look forward to your
>   response, and I hope that this will successfully resolve your issue!
>
> Thank you,
>
> Scott Rick

I am impressed by the fact that he gave much consideration to this issue and actually tested several methods.  In my case, there were two "Open in Blend..." items, so I chose the second one and it worked flawlessly.

Hope it works for you as well.

Comment: I had this command in the context menu (win store 8.1 xaml app) but seems to have disappeared with either azure SDK installation, or a win update recently (like last week or so) annoying, and for some reason I have only one "Open in Blend..." item as above, which is greyed out and disabled when I add it to the menu. Maybe it'll come back with another update ;(

Comment: It worked, thanks! But does anyone know why? Sometimes it randomly disappears and I just re-enable it. But I have to choose the second or first one some times to get it to work.

Comment: @WiteCastle That happens to me, but very rarely.  I am able to solve it by starting Blend on its own and then closing it.  When I do that, Blend option becomes available.  I'm not sure why that works or what the cause is.

Comment: I tried 2, 3 then 1 (which worked) Random (for reals)

Comment: I have a few installations of Visual Studio and it is different (1,2 or 3) on each one. Related: if I could upvote this every time I return to it you'd be beating @JonSkeet by now

Comment: @CADbloke Only JonSkeet can beat JonSkeet.

Comment: Following this route I get the error (within Blend) `page is not supported in a Windows Phone project` though the workaround (from TJ Mullen's answer [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/windowsapps/en-us/03bd5f93-e7b8-4d4d-a368-62d213109162/blend-page-is-not-supported-in-a-windows-app-project)) is to instead open the solution from within Blend and give up on the Visual Studio context menu.

Comment: @dumbledad This is definitely not a catch-all solution... I'm hoping they'll fix it in the new VS.  I've had times where the context option would not show up at all until I would start up `Blend` on its own.  I could then close `Blend` and the menu option would still be available.  It would be a good convenient option if they fix it completely, but it's not a dealbreaker for me, since VS is a pretty spectacular IDE.

Comment: Does this have anything to do with the type of project you have open? I usually have to do this for my WPF projects but not my WinRT apps.

Comment: @WiteCastle Not sure, I haven't tested this on Windows 8.

Comment: For me Visual Studio crashes at step 7. I don't think I have Blend installed at all; I can't find it anywhere.

Comment: saved my day.. Thanks much.. :)

Comment: I had three "Open with Blend"s as in the quote. The third one worked, the second was greyed out.

Answer (score 14):

You can customize it:

Keyboard Shortcut: [how to](http://blendrocks.com/2013/02/26/open-in-blend-shortcut/)

Integration in context menu:

- Tools->Customize
- Click on Commands tab
- Click on Context menu and choose "Project and Solution Context Menus | Item
- Click on Add Command
- Select View as Category
- Select 'Open in Blend' command

You get this context menu option now for every item but that should not hurt...

Comment: As @B.K. notes below, there are multiple "Open in Blend..." commands - chosing the 2nd one also worked for me for WPF applications.

Answer (score 2):

When working on a Silverlight, Windows Phone or Windows Store app project, you can use the View -> Open in Blend command to open your current active tab/code XAML window in Blend.

The above menu choice is not available for WPF apps only.  No idea why.

Comment: When my current tab is MainWindow.xaml, there is no View->Open in Blend. When I right click MainWindow.xaml, there is no Open in Blend. Just tried that in C# Wpf application.

Comment: If its not available in WPF apps, in what apps its available?

Comment: It's normally there in Silverlight apps, but I found this thread because this morning it isn't...

Comment: It's back today.  I have no idea why.  In fact, the option appears 3 times on my VIEW menu, with one or more ghosted out, depending on the type of file I've got active.