# WPF 4.5 doesn’t show the option to open the project in Microsoft Blend

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2013, blend

In my WPF 4.5 project in Visual Studio 2013, when I right clicked the name of my project it doesn’t show the option to open in Microsoft Blend…..

How I can open my project in Microsoft Blend???

Thanks!!!

Regards,

Comment: Just open it from Blend itself? Which version are you using?

Comment: I am using Blend for Visual Studio 2013. But, when I tried to open the project with Blend for Visual Studio 2013, it didn't show anything..... I don't see the project nor the UI of my WPF 4.5 project.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where is the shortcut "Open in Blend" in Visual Studio 2013?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19802227/where-is-the-shortcut-open-in-blend-in-visual-studio-2013)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you open Projects panel in Blend for Visual Studio 2013 after opening the solution file. Then you can open .xaml files from there.