# Cannot open WPF application in Expression Blend 4

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2013, expression-blend-4

I have built a wpf application in visual studio and would like to get the project into expression blend to design the view.

I have Visual studio 2013 Premium installed and Expression Blend 4 installed. I have been following the instructions in this link [Getting started with Blend for Visual Studio 2013](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/jj171012.aspx)
It states:

> Blend is installed when you install Visual Studio. To locate Blend, type Blend in the Search box.
>
> You can also open a project in Blend from within Visual Studio. With the project open in Visual Studio, do one of the following:
>
> Right-click the project file in the Solution Explorer, and then click Open in Blend.
> On the View menu, click Open in Blend.

The open with blend option is not available on my wpf project. I have also tried opening the project directly in blend but get "(unsupported project)" Have I done anything wrong or are there any good links explaining how to do this?

Comment: My impression of designing in Blend is if you are more comfortable with Photoshop use Blend.. if you are used to Visual Studio.. stick with Visual studio because you can design well in both, one set of tools panders to a different crowd than the other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem. The problem was I was trying to open my project with expression blend 4. When looking closer I had to open my project with "Blend for Visual Studio 2013" Still unsure as to why the open in Blend option does not appear

Answer (score 0):

To help others here is a good workaround:

[questions/19802227/where-is-the-shortcut-open-in-blend-in-visual-studio-2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19802227/where-is-the-shortcut-open-in-blend-in-visual-studio-2013)

Hope this will help someone else.

Simon